# How to install external Python dependencies for Spark workers in a PySpark cluster?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am running a Spark job with a PySpark user-defined function (UDF) that requires the `requests` package, which is not a standard built-in Python package. When executing the job, I encounter the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'`. I understand that the dependencies are missing on the workers, causing the UDF to fail.

I tried following the instructions in the official documentation (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/user_guide/python_packaging.html) using `pyspark.SparkContext.addPyFile()`, but I couldn't get it to work.

Could someone provide a simple guide or example on how to install external Python dependencies for Spark workers in a PySpark cluster? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved my problem. For anyone else facing a similar problem, these steps seem like a viable solution.

1. Execute the following command under the root directory of your project:

```bash
pip install --platform manylinux2014_x86_64 --target=dependencies --implementation cp --python-version 3.11 --only-binary=:all: --upgrade requests
```

If you are using Poetry, the command should be:

```bash
poetry run pip install --platform manylinux2014_x86_64 --target=dependencies --implementation cp --python-version 3.11 --only-binary=:all: --upgrade requests
```

This command installs the `requests` package into a folder named `dependencies`, which is targeting the `manylinux2014_x86_64` + Python 3.11 executor (worker) environment.

2. Zip all the files in the `dependencies` folder into a file named `dependencies.zip`, which serves as the zipped Python packages mentioned in the official documentation.
3. Make the following adjustments to your code:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as sf

spark.sparkContext.addPyFile('dependencies.zip')

def func(a):
    import requests
    # your code here

spark.udf.register("func", sf.udf(func))
df = spark.sql('SELECT func(...) FROM ...')
```

By following these steps, the `requests` package should be correctly distributed to the workers in your Spark cluster, allowing your UDF to execute without any issues related to missing dependencies.